# How to upgrade npm to latest from v5.4.1 after I have installed Nodejs v9.0.0

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

**status**: It seems that NodeJS have an [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16649)
 which is still not resolved:

**OS**:Windows

On my machine I started with `NodeJS v.7.5.0` and `npm v.5.4.2`.

Downloaded and installed `Nodejs v.9.0.0`, but npm did upgrade to `npm v5.5.1`

When tried to upgrade my npm with `npm install npm@latest -g` the following error traceback appeared:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v9.0.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe: src\node_zlib.cc:430: Assertion `args.Length() == 7 && "init(windowBits, level, memLevel, strategy, writeResult, writeCallback," " dictionary)"' failed.
```

Any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: If I try to install `node v8.9.0` it says `A later version of Node.js is already installed. Setup will now exit`

Comment: Are you using the version of npm that is bundled with Node 9?

Comment: I am missing exactly that. It's the version from my older intallation of nodejs

Comment: how to change which version of npm it should be using?

Comment: The problem was that I had to upgrade my npm to the latest version before i install the new version of NodeJS

Answer (score 1):

Remove both installations and install [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script). (or [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows))

Then, you just run:

```
nvm install 7.5.0
```

And:

```
nvm install 9
```

This will install each nodejs version with its corresponding npm version.

Comment: just added the windows version of the tool to your answer

Comment: this seems to be usefull. I tried installing node v9, but the npm -v is still saying 5.4.2

Comment: i tried: `nvm use 7.5.0` then `npm install npm -g` and then `nvm use 9.0.0` and it works now. The problem was that I needed to upgrade my npm before installing the new NodeJS version

Comment: accepting your answer because you included this nice tool for transition between the NodeJS versions

Answer (score 0):

use this for npm upgrade
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-upgrade

for node
`npm cache clean

npm update -g`

Comment: windows tag is for reason

Comment: `npm cache clean` says: npm does not support Node.js v9.0.0 same with `npm update -g`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Uninstall node
- Delete `%AppData%\npm`
- Delete `%AppData%\npm-cache`
- Install Node 9.0.0